# Using rasterio and rio_color command line problem/question

Tags: raster, command-line

I'm an amateur when it comes to the command line.

My problem is that the script I'm trying to run (rio) is in the Python\Python36-32\Scripts folder on my C:drive and I'm trying to run it using images found on my f:drive raid as input, but I cant seem to get the command to recognize the path to the imagery even when typing out the full path F:\imagery\input.tif. This command works fine when input.tif and out.tif are in the same dir as the script (Python\Python36-32\Scripts) but I want to be able to run this script on any directory I choose.

How can I achieve this?

I can run RIO from anywhere as I added the scripts folder to the path, so the problem is getting the command to recognize a different directory/drive for the input output. I already tried setting the F:\imagery directory to the path but that didn't work and my google searches are not turning up much for me as I am not to sure what to search for.

Here is the command:

```
rio color -d uint8 -j 1 input.tif out.tif sigmoidal rgb 2 0.35
```

and here is a link to rio (im using command line interface) https://github.com/mapbox/rio-color

and rasterio: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/cli.rst

Comment: What error message do you get? I assume you're on Windows, is that correct? Where are you specifying the full path to the images in your command? You shouldnt

Comment: I'm getting Error: Invalid value for "src_path": Path "F:\imagedirectory\input.tif" does not exist.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add F:\imagery to your %PATH% environment variable as this variable is for executable files (.com, .exe, .dll etc) not for where to look for data. If you have your %PATH% set correctly you could navigate to F:\Imagery in your DOS (CMD window) by typing F: (return) then CD F:\Imagery (return).. try to run your rio from there if it's having trouble with paths. By far the most common problem with full paths is SPACES, you have to quote your full path if it contains *any* spaces. Is your directory called imagery or imagerydirectory? Try drag 'n drop from explorer.

Comment: This is what im doing now. I launch up command prompt as admin, type F: to switch drives and then cd imagery which puts me into the correct dir. I can then run rio (which works), but like I said above it doesnt like the path to my input even though im running it on the F:drive. There are no spaces in any of my paths.

Comment: If you're already in F:\Imagery (your prompt should say F:\Imagery>) and try to run rio color -d uint8 -j 1 input.tif out.tif sigmoidal rgb 2 0.35 with just the file name an no path are you still getting the error? Do you have GDAL? if so what do you get when you type GDALInfo input.tif?

Comment: Confirmed my prompt says F:\Imagery> and it still gives error when run without full path. I do have GDAL (I even made sure by trying pip install gdal again and it said requirements satisfied), but when I do GDALinfo input.tif I get 'GDALinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. And I dont have any scripts called GDALinfo in my python scripts dir.

Comment: GDALinfo is in python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\osgeo and I didnt have that in my paths so thats prob. why I couldnt use it im guessing. Should I set all of the folders within my python directory to path?  Thank you for your help by the way I appreciate your time.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I figured out the issue..when I renamed my input.tif file earlier from its original name I accidentally included .tif in the end of its name.... so to use it as input in the f:\image directory I would have needed to type input.tif.tif I have it working now, but maybe you could help me with another question I have about the command line. How would I go about iterating a folder of tifs with this command? Thanks

Comment: It would be a good idea to set GDAL into your path. You can drag and drop the executable (GDALInfo.exe) into your command window, add a space, then drag and drop the image and press return. Ah I see, that's a fairly common problem if 'hide file extensions for known types' is set in windows. To iterate you can create a python script, either with os.listdir or os.walk.